# Insert Image in Google Colab Text Cell

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to insert an image to a text cell in google colab which I have already uploaded in google drive.
For this I use markdown syntax:
![Name]("Get shareable link")

But it doesn't work. My link looks like this:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/16teg5zUQhl01IOgvnP61aFjj0kFrviwr/view?usp=sharing`

and not like this

`https://docs.google.com/uc?id=----`

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can mount the drive at the left-hand file/section explorer and from there refer the image path

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: you can use the Colab markdown in the Text cell

Answer (score 5):

You can change to direct URL format

```
![](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=16teg5zUQhl01IOgvnP61aFjj0kFrviwr)
```

Then it should show to you. It's not shown to me because it's not shared publicly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try from left-hand side or from code-block
If you try from code, copy the token and paste on the textbox and hit 'enter'
then 'refresh' left hand side panel using the refresh button (beside drive-mount button)
the go to the image and right click copy path

[image]

[image]

[image]