# How to add pictures in colab text

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have used Jupyter notebook before and there is no problem to add pictures in the text cells.

In Colab, I have tried all the different ways I can come up with and I have searched the web. I have found a lot of solutions but none work for me. I think that the format of the downloadable link differs from the suggested solutions I have found. I have tried to modify the links in different ways but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I Found this in stack overflow: [Insert Image in Google Colab Text Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154277/insert-image-in-google-colab-text-cell)

I have uploaded my image to Google drive. If I right click the image I can select "Get Link". I think that one shall make the link "Open". Click "Copy link" and return to the markdown cell.
Where you want the image positioned, write "![]([https://drive.google.com/uc?id="](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=%22) then Ctrl + V to add the copied link, but delete all but the bold code as below :
"https://drive.google.com/file/d/**1CDIZwkVNiKNmaskHPwnCFTkt-4_RxIhP**/view?usp=sharing"
The resulting image link should look something like this:
"![ ] (https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CDIZwkVNiKNmaskHPwnCFTkt-4_RxIhP)"
(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

It is only just about adding a `!`.
Let me give an example,

1. Add a link.
   [image: Add a link]
2. Paste Image link
   [image]
3. Then put `!` before link text.(eg `![link text](https://i.example.com/e7e8ea16d242676.png`))
   [image]

Comment: My problem was, I have the picture in my computer. There is a button Insert image in the menu. The image is uploaded to the rendered cell but the image huge code is listed in the markdown cell.

Comment: show screenshots about the scenario, the question above mentioned doesnot match anything what you are saying now, we can only help if you can explain what you need help in.