# Further question on "insert image in Google colab text cell"

Tags: google-colaboratory

I followed the question and answers to [question on inserting images into Colab text cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154277/insert-image-in-google-colab-text-cell/63156016#63156016?newreg=ed8219bb39564b07975e70071db73cfe). Similar to that poster, I wish to place images into text cells rather than bring them up using Python code cells.

The source of the images is intended to be files in a subfolder of the project containing the Jupyter notebook whose discussion I want to enrich with photos and drawings. It is important to keep the notebook and supporting files, including images and data, in a single encompassing folder. (I expect to work on dozens of such projects, each with its own assembly of files in separate project folders.)

In order to achieve this I mounted the Google drive containing the image files by running

```
  from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I clicked on the file folder in the left sidebar and expanded directories until I could select the image file I want to use and obtain its path. Then I tried using either of the following in a text cell:

`<img src="/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Lab13 Mechanisms/Figures/PantographCloseUp.JPG" alt="Close up of a pantograph made with LEGO Technics and LEGO Mindstorms components">`

`![Close up of a pantograph made with LEGO Technics and LEGO Mindstorms components](/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab%20Notebooks/Lab13%20Mechanisms/Figures/PantographCloseUp.JPG)`

Neither of these work: no image appears. Right clicking on the empty box containing a question mark and choosing inspect element and then the tab "sources", I clicked on the image resource and got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a states of 403 ()."  I understand this is some sort of authorization fault (???).

(The image is set to be shared with anyone with the link.)

What is going on? Why don't the image-in-text-cell methods work using the file paths on the mounted drive? (Ideally, too, I would like to use a relative path: `Figures/PantographCloseUp.JPG`)

---

Please note that the following does produce an image in a text cell but is not a terribly convenient way of keeping track of image sources:

`<img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1dYjA01xQqah0l2cSQYcd6U0UFrfH3LPK'/>`

Also, I can run code to display the image using the desired file path but this is also not convenient because a user (a student) of the document would have to run all of these cells just to look at the pictures.

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Lab13 Mechanisms/Figures/PantographCloseUp.JPG")
```